# high memory usage 100% rss feed attack

Tags: memory-leak

I am getting a lot of traffic to my website in /feed here is the log

Ip Address - - [10/Feb/2016:14:47:58 +0300] "GET /feed/ HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; SM-G7102 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36"

Ip Address - - [10/Feb/2016:14:47:58 +0300] "GET /feed/ HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; GT-I9195 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36"

Ip Address - - [10/Feb/2016:14:47:49 +0300] "GET /feed/ HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; GT-I9060C Build/KTU84P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/33.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36"

Ip Address - - [10/Feb/2016:14:47:58 +0300] "GET /feed/ HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G900F Build/LRX21T; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/44.0.2403.117 Mobile Safari/537.36"

Ip Address - - [10/Feb/2016:14:47:59 +0300] "GET /feed/ HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; Infinix X510 Build/LMY47V; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/47.0.2526.100 Mobile Safari/537.36"

Ip Address - - [10/Feb/2016:14:47:46 +0300] "GET /feed/ HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; SM-G7102 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36"

My question is :
how to block all these traffic because my memory is high 100%?

any htaccess code to block these connection please help me.

Kind Regards

Comment: Why is your server returning a 500?  What is broken behind your web server?

Comment: that time i have broken the htaccess because of the high traffic i only had to option to suspend my account or to break the htaccess i can give a 200 status

Comment: You want to block only /feed/ from all?

Comment: No. You problem is you do not cache the output. And / or use a CDN to TOTALLY ELIMINATE THOSE HITS. Run your website through Cloudflare. Put a 5 minute cache instruction on it - finished.

Comment: fredi yes just to stop these traffic

Comment: TomTom how i can use CDN? please guide me i just need to drop the hits

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are allowed to use .htaccess files (AllowOverride all), you should put in your .htaccess file in the directory:

```
$document_root/feed/
```

On apache 2.4 your .htaccess will have:

```
Require all denied
```

On apache 2.2 instead:

```
Deny from all
```

Done.

Although this seems a problem with your weDeny from all
bapp / setup and as @TomTom said in comments, a CDN is a really good idea in any any case.

Comment: I have added $document_root/feed/ to my htaccess directory but nothing is changed Please guide me

Comment: I meant, you should put an .htaccess file in a directory called feed under your document root. If your document root is /var/www/html, then put a .htaccess conf in: /var/www/html/feed/.htaccess

Comment: The content as for my answer is "Require all denied" under apache 2.4, and "Deny from all" under apache 2.2

Comment: Here is what i have done so far: i have edited to main htaccess of my website i have added this code $document_root/feed/ Deny from all  is there any steps wrong.

Comment: You have to add only "Deny from all"